# MySql multiple join taking a long time (only one of the tables is big)

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me make this query more efficient, sometimes it's taking up to 3 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT 
    up.*, 
    u.name AS learner_name, 
    g.type AS group_type, 
    l.name AS name, 
    l.type AS type, 
    l.assessment_type AS assessment_type, 
    l.id AS lesson_id, 
    s.sort AS sort 
FROM 
    cdu_user_progress up 
INNER JOIN cdu_groups g ON g.id = up.group_id 
INNER JOIN cdu_sessions s ON s.id = up.session_id 
INNER JOIN cdu_lessons l ON l.id = up.lesson_id 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = up.uid 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_teacher_id ftid ON ftid.entity_id = up.uid 
WHERE 
    (ftid.field_teacher_id_value = '6378') 
ORDER BY 
    up.id DESC 
LIMIT 15 
OFFSET 0
```

cdu_user_progress (up) is the BIG table, it contains >200k rows.  The other tables only contain a few hundred rows.

Explain returns this:

```
id |select_type |table |type   |possible_keys                            |key                                   |key_len |ref                         |rows |Extra
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |SIMPLE      |l     |ALL    |PRIMARY                                  |NULL                                  |NULL    |NULL                        |744  |Using temporary; Using filesort
1  |SIMPLE      |up    |ref    |cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, |cdu_user_progress(lesson_id, game_id) |4       |ealteach_main.l.id          |133  |
   |            |      |       |game_id, date),cdu_user_progress(uid,    |                                      |        |                            |     |
   |            |      |       |lesson_id, level, game_id, score),       |                                      |        |                            |     |
   |            |      |       |cdu_user_progress(lesson_id, game_id),   |                                      |        |                            |     |
   |            |      |       |idx_score,idx_id_update                  |                                      |        |                            |     |
1  |SIMPLE      |g     |eq_ref |PRIMARY                                  |PRIMARY                               |4       |ealteach_main.up.group_id   |1    |
1  |SIMPLE      |ftid  |ref    |entity_id                                |entity_id                             |4       |ealteach_main.up.uid        |1    |Using index condition; Using where
1  |SIMPLE      |u     |eq_ref |PRIMARY                                  |PRIMARY                               |4       |ealteach_main.up.uid        |1    |Using where
1  |SIMPLE      |s     |eq_ref |PRIMARY                                  |PRIMARY                               |4       |ealteach_main.up.session_id |1    |
```

Not sure if I'm reading it right, but it appears to be scanning the whole of the cdu_lessons (l) table - is this where the bottle neck is?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Does cdu_user_progress have any fields that might be useful as an additional filter, given that you only want the last 15 records?

Comment: Not really, there is a date field, but I still need to return the most recent 15 entries regardless...

Comment: I'm using the field_data_field_teacher_id to filter out some of the rows in cdu_user_progress - perhaps I should put this as a where clause?

Comment: It is scanning `cdu_lessons` because you are asking ALL the data from cdu_lessons,the only constraint is the JOIN(s)

Comment: I want only the rows of cdu_lessons that appear as the 15 most recent up.lesson_ids in cdu_user_progress...

Comment: Also it appears that `field_teacher_id_value` is not indexed.Looking again it might help if you start the JOIN on a table with fewer rows,like `field_data_field_teacher_id`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `INNER JOINS`, make sure you first include column from other table and then the joined table column. This will optimise your query by 10-20%, and it's also a good practice for other queries, for example:

```
INNER JOIN cdu_groups g ON up.group_id = g.id 
INNER JOIN cdu_sessions s ON up.session_id = s.id
```

and so on for other tables..

Comment: Ok, will do thanks.  This doesn't change the EXPLAIN output, but I guess it's executing 10%/20% quicker...

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting different execution plans for `g.id = up.group_id` and `up.group_id = g.id`???

Comment: Of course, check out offical MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html . They use the same method in all of their examples.

Comment: I don't see this behaviour anywhere mentioned and I would consider it a flaw if the order of the fields compared really made a difference. It just would make no sense and I cannot imagine it to be so. Did you ever try this and got two different execution plans? I doubt that.

Comment: It isn't my prime goal to convince you @ThorstenKettner, as long as I helped the quy who made a question (who btw has confirmed my solution).

Comment: Er, no, lombrozo said the explain plan remained *unchanged* -- which would mean that the change makes no difference at all. They had a feeling that the query got executed quicker, though, which is no surprise, because often queries get executed faster when run again (which some data already in cache). Anyway, if lombrozo is happy with this solution, that's okay with me :-)

Answer (score 0):

We consider the table `cdu_user_progress` big and there is only one thing in your query that reduces the rows to read from it: that there must exist a `field_data_field_teacher_id` record with `field_teacher_id_value = '6378'` for it.

The explain plan however shows the DBMS joins the lesson and group first (for *all* `cdu_user_progress` records). I wonder why this is so. How much does the field teacher thing narrow the result? Do you get 1% of the `cdu_user_progress` records? Or 90% The DBMS seems to think it may be a lot, so it doesn't bother to use this criteria to narrow the intermediate result. Maybe it really is that many records you'd get, then the DBMS is right and this simply can't get fast. If, however, it is few rows only and the DBMS is wrong, then we must see to it that the DBMS knows about the restrictiveness of the field teacher criteria.

First of all: How many records do I get from `field_data_field_teacher_id` with one `field_teacher_id_value`? Have an index an that field, so as to make the distribution known to the DBMS. Is it one record per ID value only? Then this is a unique key and should get a unique index. That would be an obvious thing. For the other case, when an ID value gets you 2 or 10 or 100 records, you'd have a non-unique index and the DBMS wouldn't know yet about the distribution. You would have to run `ANALYZE TABLE` after having created the index, so the DBMS stores the needed statistic data.

As it's mere existence of a matching `field_data_field_teacher_id` record you are interested in, you should make this obvious in your query, too. Use EXISTS or IN (or even = , when there can be only one matching record).

```
SELECT 
    up.*, 
    u.name AS learner_name, 
    g.type AS group_type, 
    l.name AS name, 
    l.type AS type, 
    l.assessment_type AS assessment_type, 
    l.id AS lesson_id, 
    s.sort AS sort 
FROM 
    cdu_user_progress up 
INNER JOIN cdu_groups g ON g.id = up.group_id 
INNER JOIN cdu_sessions s ON s.id = up.session_id 
INNER JOIN cdu_lessons l ON l.id = up.lesson_id 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = up.uid 
WHERE up.uid IN
(
  SELECT ftid.entity_id
  FROM field_data_field_teacher_id ftid
  WHERE ftid.field_teacher_id_value = '6378'
)
ORDER BY 
    up.id DESC 
LIMIT 15 
OFFSET 0;
```

(Why do you use quotes on a number, by the way? Isn't field_teacher_id_value numeric? Does it contain non-numeric ID values, too?)

Then it is `uid` that limits the rows to read from the table `cdu_user_progress`. As it is an ID there is certainly already an index an that column, right? (There should be an index for every foreign key.) So again, how many records do I get with one `uid`? To make this known to the DBMS, run `ANALYZE TABLE` on `cdu_user_progress`, too.

If all this doesn't help, you may want to show the road to go explicitly in your query:

```
SELECT 
    up.*, 
    u.name AS learner_name, 
    g.type AS group_type, 
    l.name AS name, 
    l.type AS type, 
    l.assessment_type AS assessment_type, 
    l.id AS lesson_id, 
    s.sort AS sort 
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM cdu_user_progress
  WHERE uid IN
  (
    SELECT ftid.entity_id
    FROM field_data_field_teacher_id ftid
    WHERE ftid.field_teacher_id_value = '6378'
  )
  ORDER BY up.id DESC 
  LIMIT 15 
) up
INNER JOIN cdu_groups g ON g.id = up.group_id 
INNER JOIN cdu_sessions s ON s.id = up.session_id 
INNER JOIN cdu_lessons l ON l.id = up.lesson_id 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = up.uid 
ORDER BY up.id DESC;
```

(Well, you may want to do this anyhow, for it very clearly shows what you are doing and may help maintainability.)

Here is the description for `ANALYZE TABLE` in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html